# How to Remove a Running Application from a Node in a YARN-Managed Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

** Problem **

I'm working with a Hadoop cluster with Yarn resource management (specifically Dataproc cluster on GCP). I am running into an issue with long spark processes (spark in notebooks), where we will allocate executors from node A for the application, but after the executors finish and are deleted Yarn still says that the application is running on said node A.

This becomes problematic for graceful decommissioning, where it will not decommission node A because it sees it's still running the application -- despite no resources actually being utilized from the node.

My goal is to find a way to essentially unregister the application from the nodes, without stopping the application.

** My Thoughts **

I've tried searching through the Yarn / Hadoop / Dataproc properties to see if there was a configuration setting related to the Node Manager that would reach out to the Resource Manager to unregister the application from it after all the application's requested containers finish. I was not able to find anything relevant.